# Orthogonalizing brownian path

Tags: stochastic-calculus, monte-carlo, brownian-motion

I want to improve the stability of my SDE sample (statistical properties do not change much when using a different seed). I am using a sobol brownian bridge to generate the brownian path increments dw. I have seen a noticeable improvement when I use qr/gram-schmidt orthogonalization of my dw samples as it makes the samples completely independent.
Is this a general practise or am I doing something wrong (as gram schmidt is a nonlinear process making the samples non gaussian).

Comment: This is a general practise. As far as I know the most common way of doing it is using a Cholesky decomposition (because it's available in many libraries and is also used on the other direction, to correlate the BM), but I that's more of a implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks. It does lead to a general improvement in performance but  it can gets tricky for path dependent options. Sometimes, my prices show more variance (when I change seeds) with orthogonalized samples. Also, when I run simple tests like measuring the probability of being between .1 and .2, non orthogonalized samples perform better.

Comment: That seems odd. Whats the number of samples you are using?

Comment: around 8000. But this is not so odd, is it? We fix the mean and the variance but the distribution isnt exactly Gaussian now (since we applied a small but non linear transform) so mean and variance do not completely capture all its properties.. The question is, does it perform better in practice..

Comment: Thats is true that you no longer have a gaussian, but why would the "best" sample lead to a worsening in the prices variance? I wouldn't expect that.